# remove smoothness effect on edge with matplotlib pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, blur, smoothing

I'd like to remove an blur effect on edge when plotting an image. The following is a minimal reproducible code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.zeros((512,512))
im[30:100,40:80]=1
im[200:250,300:350]=2
plt.figure(figsize=(20,13))
plt.imshow(im)
```

[image]
[image]

You can see the green on the edge of a rectangle. Is there any help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with adding `interpolation="none"` to `plt.imshow(..)`.

[image]